# Obtener el tiempo restante entre dos fechas Date en Android

Tags: android, date

Realizo una Aplicación donde necesito obtener el tiempo restante para el día de un evento, utilizando la clase `CountDownTimer` logre obtener un contador de días horas y fechas pero no se me ocurre como obtener el tiempo restante.

Para ello tengo dos fechas establecidas por medio del dos `Date` y necesito saber el tiempo restante entre ellas, para la fecha del evento tengo el formato:

```
Date(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second);
```

Y para el tiempo actual simplemente genero un nuevo date

```
Date date = new Date();
```

Como puedo obtener el tiempo restante en días, horas, minutos y segundos.

Mi código en el que solo tengo el contador con el tiempo actual hasta el evento:

Primero declare las variables:

```
private TextView countDown;
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
private long initialTime =
            DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS * 110 +
            DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS * 9 +
            DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS * 3 +
            DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS * 42;
```

y después lo maneje en el `CountDownTimer`:

```
       countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(initialTime, 1000) {
            StringBuilder time = new StringBuilder();

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                time.setLength(0);
                // Use days if appropriate
                if(millisUntilFinished > DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS) {
                    long count = millisUntilFinished / DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS;
                    if(count > 1)
                        time.append(count).append(" Dias ");
                    else
                        time.append(count).append(" Dia ");

                    millisUntilFinished %= DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS;
                }

                time.append(DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(Math.round(millisUntilFinished / 1000d)));
                countDown.setText(time.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                countDown.setText(DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(0));
                countDown.setText("Dia del evento");
            }


        }.start();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primero hay que obtener la diferencia en milisegundos:

```
long diff = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
```

Luego hacer las operaciones para saber la diferencia en la unidad que requieras:

```
long segundos = diff / 1000;
long minutos = segundos / 60;
long horas = minutos / 60;
long dias = horas / 24;
```

Debes considerar que al hacer la división entera se introduce en el cálculo un error por truncamiento.

Answer (score 1):

Con este método lo puedes lograr y es similar a lo que estas realizando:

```
public String getDiferencia(Date fechaInicial, Date fechaFinal){

    long diferencia = fechaFinal.getTime() - fechaInicial.getTime();

    Log.i("MainActivity", "fechaInicial : " + fechaInicial);
    Log.i("MainActivity", "fechaFinal : " + fechaFinal);

    long segsMilli = 1000;
    long minsMilli = segsMilli * 60;
    long horasMilli = minsMilli * 60;
    long diasMilli = horasMilli * 24;

    long diasTranscurridos = diferencia / diasMilli;
    diferencia = diferencia % diasMilli;

    long horasTranscurridos = diferencia / horasMilli;
    diferencia = diferencia % horasMilli;

    long minutosTranscurridos = diferencia / minsMilli;
    diferencia = diferencia % minsMilli;

    long segsTranscurridos = diferencia / segsMilli;

    return "diasTranscurridos: " + diasTranscurridos + " , horasTranscurridos: " + horasTranscurridos +
            " , minutosTranscurridos: " + minutosTranscurridos + " , segsTranscurridos: " + segsTranscurridos;


}
```

Determinamos las fechas en las cuales deseamos obtener la diferencia:

```
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    Date fechaI = null, fechaF = null;
    try {
        fechaI = simpleDateFormat.parse("1/6/2016 12:20:12");
         //fechaF puede ser la fecha actual o tu puedes asignarala,
         //por ejemplo: fechaF = simpleDateFormat.parse("2/6/2016 15:40:42");
         fechaF = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

A partir de los valores ejecutamos el método `getDiferencia()` con la fecha inicial y la final:

```
  Log.i(TAG,  getDiferencia(fechaI , fechaF));
```

El método internamente imprime la fecha inicial y final, para que puedas verificar los valores:

```
fechaInicial : Wed Jun 01 00:20:12 CDT 2016
fechaFinal : Thu Jun 02 11:32:16 CDT 2016
```

y obtiene un string con los valores de la diferencia:

```
diasTranscurridos: 1 , horasTranscurridos: 11 , minutosTranscurridos: 12 , segsTranscurridos: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Agrego mi solución completa para mi problema para futuras preguntas.

Primero Declare las variables a utilizar.

```
private TextView countDown;
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer; 
private Date eventDate, presentDate;
private Calendar calendar;
private long initialTime;
```

Después inicializamos la variable `calendar` con una nueva instancia y enviamos la fecha de nuestro evento futuro.

```
 calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
 calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.AUGUST);
 calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 20);
 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);
 calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
 calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

Ahora inicializamos las variables de tipo `Date` que son `eventDate` = día del evento y `presentDate` = día actual, la primera obtiene su valor del calendario creado anterior mente y la segunda del día en curso.

```
 eventDate = calendar.getTime();
 presentDate = new Date();
```

Paso siguiente obtenemos la diferencia en mili segundos asignando primero el día del evento y después el día actual, los resultados los guardamos en  una variable tipo `long` y los enviamos a `Log` para verificar que el resultado no sea negativo, de ser así las fechas están mal asignadas.

```
long diff = eventDate.getTime() - presentDate.getTime();
Log.d("dateEvent", String.valueOf(eventDate));
Log.d("dateActual", String.valueOf(presentDate));
Log.d("diff", String.valueOf(diff));
```

Paso siguiente obtenemos la equivalencia en días, horas, minutos y segundos con estas operaciones matemáticas simples, todos los resultados se guardan en variables tipo `long`.

Esto nos dara como resultado por ejemplo:

> diff equivale a 5 dias 3 horas 23 minutos y 5 segundos

```
/**
 * Explicación:
 * segundos = (milisegundos / 1 segundo en milisegundos) mod 60 segundos de un minuto
 */
long seconds =(diff/1000)%60;
long minutes=(diff/(1000*60))%60;
long hours=(diff/(1000*60*60))%24;
long days=(diff/(1000*60*60*24))%365;
```

Como yo necesito hacer un contador hacia la fecha, inicializo la variable `ìnitialTime` con el valor de la diferencia `diff`.

```
 initialTime = diff;
```

Y después asigno los valores al constructor para inicializar la variable `countDownTimer`:

```
countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(initialTime, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                int days = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / 1000) / 86400);
                int hours = (int) (((millisUntilFinished / 1000)
                        - (days * 86400)) / 3600);
                int minutes = (int) (((millisUntilFinished / 1000)
                        - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
                int seconds = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60);

                String countDownText = String.format("%2d Dias %2d Hr %2d Min %2d Seg", days, hours, minutes, seconds);
                countDown.setText(countDownText);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                countDown.setText(DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(0));
            }

        }.start();
```

Con esto el `CountDownTimer` funciona desde la fecha actual hacia la del evento.