# Diferencia en días entre dos fechas Java

Tags: java

Quisiera saber como sacar la diferencia en días entre dos fechas dadas, entregadas en este formato *yyyy-mm-dd*, tengo esto, pero no me da.

```
public static int diferenciaDias(String ingreso, String retiro){
    int dias=0,meses=0,anos=0;
    LocalDate i = LocalDate.parse(ingreso, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
    LocalDate r = LocalDate.parse(retiro, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
    
    Period period = Period.between(i, r);
    
    dias= Math.abs(period.getDays()); meses=Math.abs(period.getMonths()); anos=Math.abs(period.getYears());
    
    dias=dias+1;
    
    if(dias>=30){
        dias=0; meses=meses+1;
    }if(meses>=12){
        meses=0;anos=anos+1;
    }
    
    
    return dias;
}í
```

Comment: ESto ya se pregunto en el sitio: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11661/obtener-el-tiempo-restante-entre-dos-fechas-date-en-android?rq=1 https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/196826/c%c3%b3mo-sacar-la-diferencia-en-horas-de-dos-fechas-en-android?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La verdad que tienes infinidad de métodos para calcularlo

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    //usamos SimpleDateFormat
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    //creamos una variable date con la fecha inicial
    Date fechaInicial = dateFormat.parse("2016-02-14");
    //variable date con la fecha final
    Date fechaFinal = dateFormat.parse("2016-03-22");
    //calculamos los días restando la inicial de la final y dividiendolo entre los milisegundos que tiene un día y almacenamos el resultado en la variable entera
    int dias = (int) ((fechaFinal.getTime() - fechaInicial.getTime()) / 86400000);
    //se imprime el resultado
    System.out.println("Hay " + dias + " dias de diferencia");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya existe una función que realiza esa operación:

```
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public static long diferenciaDias(String ingreso, String retiro){
        //int dias=0,meses=0,anos=0;
        LocalDate i = LocalDate.parse(ingreso, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
        LocalDate r = LocalDate.parse(retiro, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
        
        //Period period = Period.between(i, r);
        
        //dias= Math.abs(period.getDays()); meses=Math.abs(period.getMonths()); anos=Math.abs(period.getYears());
        
        //dias=dias+1;
        
        /*if(dias>=30){
            dias=0; meses=meses+1;
        }
        if(meses>=12){
            meses=0;anos=anos+1;
        }*/
        
        return ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(i, r);
        
        //return dias;
    }
```